# Specify what the Facebook "Like it" button shows on Facebook

Tags: 7, views, social-network

On our [website](http://www.adventskalender.be) we have a Facebook "Like it" button, which works fine, but if someone "likes" us, Facebook shows an ugly picture.

As we want Facebook to link to the same content on every page, also on pages which are not driven by a node but by a view, this makes Drupal node based meta tags and open graph useless, is it?

How can we tell Facebook what to show about our website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this page for more information about this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Answer (score 3):

You can also look into the [Open Graph meta tags](http://drupal.org/project/opengraph_meta) module which allows you to specify which fields Facebook looks at when constructing its likes.

Comment: This adds open graph meta tags based on node contents. We need a solution which adds the very same tags on every page. Especially on views generated pages.

Comment: sounds like you are on the right track below then by modifying your page.tpl.php to just have static meta tags in the top of each page...

Answer (score 0):

Following Lance's suggestion we tried to add the og meta tags. Unfortunately it looks like facebook is not looking at them. Any ideas?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
    xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"

...
<head>
...
    <meta property="og:title" content="Adventskalender.be | P&uuml;lss Production GmbH"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.adventskalender.be"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.adventskalender.be/pp_logo.png"/>

    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Adventskalender.be"/>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="105102305182"/>
    <meta property="og:description"
        content="&Ouml;ffnen Sie ihr Fenster und gewinnen ein iPad 2."/>

...

</head>
<body
...
```

Comment: Just like drupal and its cache, facebook has one as well and only looks at your pages again for changes once a day or something, so, give it time, and if after a day or so, then begin to worry :)

Comment: Testing with http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug will nuke the cache on the FB side.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I clicked on "like it" a day later and everything was working as expected!